# Is there a tool that shows a map with destinations and travel time from a train station?

Tags: trains, maps

Essentially a map like this [walking and public transport distance x travel time calculator](https://app.traveltime.com/) but for UK and international rail journeys.

There is the [direkt tool](https://direkt.bahn.guru/?origin=7001424) by DB which is great but it only has direct connections from a specific station.

I'd like to see either a map with a boundary of where can be reached within a set time like the first tool. Or a map with all possible destinations with times for each one (presumably limited to major cities to prevent it from becoming too crowded).

Failing a dynamic tool, a map that has this precalculated for London would do.

Comment: How about Chronotrains:
https://www.chronotrains.com/?zoom=6.1&lng=5.74&lat=50.32&stationId=8700011

Comment: That's almost perfect! Just a shame it has a limit of 5 hours. Really nice though.